# Workflow that runs once a day, and triggers at calculated date

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

What approach would be best when craeting a workflows that triggers 30 days before item expiration date. The WF would consists of a simple action, pause for 24H and then start over. But what WF type would work best, creating a WF that runs on each item, or a list WF the enumerates the list and runs each item through a foreach loop. I think its actually a site WF, or reuseable WF?

Thank

Michael

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Site Workflow. You can query the list items using HTTPWebCall matching your condition and loop through and execute your logic.

Reusable workflow is basically to attach to a list/content type and trigger on item insert / change.

Comment: do you have a resource with an example, how to use HTTPWebCall?